# styled component default props values are not getting picked up

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

**styled component**

```
const Button = styled.button`
  width: 88px;
  height: 36px;
  background:${(props) => buttonTheme[props.buttonTheme].backgroundValue}; 
  box-shadow:${(props) => buttonTheme[props.buttonTheme].boxShadowValue};
  border:${(props) => buttonTheme[props.buttonTheme].borderValue} ;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 5px 0;

`;
```

Default values

```
Button.defaultProps = {
  buttonTheme: "defaultButtonTheme"
};

const buttonTheme = {
  defaultButtonTheme: {
    borderValue: "0",
    boxShadowValue: "0",
    backgroundValue: "0"
  },
  defaultButton: {
    backgroundValue: "#E0E0E0",
    boxShadowValue: "0px 2px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2)",
    color: "#3F3F3F"
  },
  hoverFocusType1Button: {
    backgroundValue: "#AEAEAE",
    boxShadowValue: "0px 2px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2)",
    color: "#3F3F3F"
  },
  OutlineVariantButton: {
    borderValue: "1px solid #3D5AFE",
    color: "#3D5AFE"
  },
  hoverFocusType2Button: {
    backgroundValue: "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.1)",
    borderValue: "1px solid #3D5AFE",
    color: "#3D5AFE"
  },
  textVariantButton: {
    color: "#3D5AFE"
  },
  hoverFocusType3Button: {
    backgroundValue: "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.1)",
    color: "#3D5AFE"
  },
}
```

Let's say I return JSX

```
<div>
        <Button buttonTheme="defaultButton">Default</Button>
</div>
```

My expectation is which ever values are missing in this prop, it should pick up from default but it's not working as expected.

e.g. In above case I expect

```
borderValue: "0",
```

But I still see border to this button and not sure from where is it coming ?

Comment: Does it work with any of the other theme properties?

Comment: I don't think so, is there a way to console log `props` so that I can get to know which values are getting picked ?

Comment: I think you can do something like this:

border: ${(props) => {
    console.log(buttonTheme[props.buttonTheme].borderValue);
    return buttonTheme[props.buttonTheme].borderValue;
  }};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting what you want because `defaultButtonTheme` is not being merged at any time with the other themes.

To accomplish what you want, you can do:

**1.** Create two objects theme, one with the default values and another one with the themes:

```
const defaultButtonTheme = {
  borderValue: "0",
  boxShadowValue: "0",
  backgroundValue: "0",
};

const buttonTheme = {
  defaultButton: {
    backgroundValue: "#E0E0E0",
    boxShadowValue: "0px 2px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2)",
    color: "#3F3F3F",
  },
  hoverFocusType1Button: {
    backgroundValue: "#AEAEAE",
    boxShadowValue: "0px 2px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2)",
    color: "#3F3F3F",
  },
  OutlineVariantButton: {
    borderValue: "1px solid #3D5AFE",
    color: "#3D5AFE",
  },
  hoverFocusType2Button: {
    backgroundValue: "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.1)",
    borderValue: "1px solid #3D5AFE",
    color: "#3D5AFE",
  },
  textVariantButton: {
    color: "#3D5AFE",
  },
  hoverFocusType3Button: {
    backgroundValue: "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.1)",
    color: "#3D5AFE",
  },
};
```

**2.** Change your styled button to:

```js
const Button = styled.button`
  width: 88px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 5px 0;

  ${(props) => {
    const defaultThemeConcatenated = Object.assign(
      {},
      defaultButtonTheme,
      buttonTheme[props.buttonTheme]
    );

    return css`
      background: ${defaultThemeConcatenated.backgroundValue};
      box-shadow: ${defaultThemeConcatenated.boxShadowValue};
      border: ${defaultThemeConcatenated.borderValue};
    `;
  }}
`;
```

Now we are concatenating the informed  theme with the default theme, and any properties that the informed theme doesn't have, it will get from default theme.

And as you seen, i'm using `css`, so do don´t forget to import it too.

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
```

In this case, i included `return css` to let it clear that i'm returning some styles from this part of code and than, it will set the theme color of my vscode to this lines.

You can do like:

```
return `
      background: ${defaultThemeConcatenated.backgroundValue};
      box-shadow: ${defaultThemeConcatenated.boxShadowValue};
      border: ${defaultThemeConcatenated.borderValue};
    `;
```

But in this case, `background, box-shadow and border` will not be set with the theme color that i like. It's more like a convention.

Here's a code snippet to check the code working.

```js
const defaultButtonTheme = {
  borderValue: "0",
  boxShadowValue: "0",
  backgroundValue: "0",
};

const buttonTheme = {
  defaultButton: {
    backgroundValue: "#E0E0E0",
    boxShadowValue: "0px 2px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2)",
    color: "#3F3F3F",
  },
  hoverFocusType1Button: {
    backgroundValue: "#AEAEAE",
    boxShadowValue: "0px 2px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2)",
    color: "#3F3F3F",
  },
  OutlineVariantButton: {
    borderValue: "1px solid #3D5AFE",
    color: "#3D5AFE",
  },
  hoverFocusType2Button: {
    backgroundValue: "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.1)",
    borderValue: "1px solid #3D5AFE",
    color: "#3D5AFE",
  },
  textVariantButton: {
    color: "#3D5AFE",
  },
  hoverFocusType3Button: {
    backgroundValue: "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.1)",
    color: "#3D5AFE",
  },
};

const Button = window.styled.button`
  width: 88px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 5px 0;

  ${(props) => {
    const defaultThemeConcatenated = Object.assign(
      {},
      defaultButtonTheme,
      buttonTheme[props.buttonTheme]
    );

    return window.styled.css`
      background: ${defaultThemeConcatenated.backgroundValue};
      box-shadow: ${defaultThemeConcatenated.boxShadowValue};
      border: ${defaultThemeConcatenated.borderValue};
    `;
  }}
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
 <div>
  <Button buttonTheme="defaultButton">Default</Button>
  <Button buttonTheme="hoverFocusType1Button">Default</Button>
  <Button buttonTheme="OutlineVariantButton">Default</Button>
  <Button buttonTheme="textVariantButton">Default</Button>
  <Button buttonTheme="hoverFocusType3Button">Default</Button>
 </div>     
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
div {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction:column; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-is@17.0.2/umd/react-is.production.min.jss"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components@4.0.1/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: can you please clarify why did you use `window.styled.button` ?  In Pt. 2 `window` is missing

Comment: i used `window.styled.button` just in the code snippet of stackoverflow. I cant do an `import styled from "styled-components"` in there and thats the way for the code to work in the snippet specifically. So, ignore that! you just need to use `const Button = styled.button` like item 2.

Comment: can you please reference to usage of `return css` in styled component ? I couldn't find this pattern, is it something new ?

Comment: Its not new. you can check more about it here: [https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css)

Comment: Thanks , but I didn't see explicit `return` with `css`; can you explain this last part. I've used tailwind css and `styled component` is new to me

Comment: I've updated the answer, see if that was your doubt!